# Html5 video fullscreen with the possibility to modify the video control via css

Tags: html, css, video, styles, fullscreen

[image]

I'm trying to integrate a video player or youtube or vimeo in some way to my website.
I need to include a video in the background of the site in full screen.

I would like to have more than using css3 and html controls on the video at the top left for example ..
Do you know a player that you can gesire in this way?

Tnx